# TimeSeries prediction gets it wrong on standard Sinus-curve

Tags: ssas, prediction, dmx-ssas

I'm trying out SSAS DAX Time Prediction-modeling in MSSQL 2012, but the forecasts do not match my expectation.

The input data is a perfect Sinus curve, about 300 datapoints with five repetitions [image: Input data, excel graph]. The data is loaded in the mining structure and mining model with time Microsoft_Time_Series and default algorithm parameters.

The prediction does not pick up on the Sinus-curve, but predicts an allmost linear line downwards.
[image: output]

What can I do to improve the prediction?